# Xamarin FreshMVVM PublicKeyToken=null not found'

Tags: xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I'm working on a Xamarin forms app and i am using fresh MVVM framework.
i added a button to a ContentPage that needs to open a new page.

the following error is:

```
System.Exception: 'Bux_Management.Pages.JournalsOverviewPage, Bux Management, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null not found'
```

my button in Xaml

```
<Button Text="Go to journal overview page" Command="{Binding ShowJournalOverviewPage}"/>
```

my command in my PageModel which inherits from FreshBasePageModel

```
        public Command ShowJournalOverviewPage
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () => {
                    await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<JournalsOverviewPageModel>(null);
                });
            }
        }
```

my page models are in de folder "PageModels" and they inherit from "FreshBasePageModel"
my pages are in the folder "Pages" and they inherit from "ContentPage"

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I believe that page and pagemodel must be under the same namespace

Comment: `await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<JournalsOverviewPageModel>();` ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot about your page and pagemodel class list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed it was a problem with the namespaces, first i used ViewModels and View as folders and changed it later to PageModel and Pages

Comment: @Sujay: They are the author—and it is an answer. Though it’d probably be a more useful answer, admittedly, we’re it to include the additional context from Fabri’s comment which led to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

it is the problem with name space both the page and ViewModel to be in the same namespace